# Selling Apartments Recursive Definition

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

my task is the following:

> A construction company has completed a new building with A apartments
>   that are all available in the market. There are B potential buyers for
>   these apartments.
>
> Given a buyer b and two arrays s; p, the value s[b] corresponds to the
>   number of apartments buyer b would like to buy and p[b] corresponds to
>   the money the buyer is willing to pay for the apartments. The goal of
>   the company is to determine the maximum profit that it can achieve by
>   selling the apartments to the appropriate buyers. Note that not all
>   apartments need to be sold, and a buyer gets either all the apartments
>   he asked for or none.
>
> Example: Assume there are 8 apartments to be sold and 4 potential
>   buyers. The number of apartments that each buyer wants to buy and the
>   price they are will- ing to pay are available in the arrays: s = [4;
>   1; 2; 3] and p = [8; 1; 10; 9], respectively. The maximum prot that
>   can be achieved is 20.
>   3.1 [3 points] Assume P(b; a) is the maximum prot achieved when the requests of the rst b buyers are taken into consideration and when a
>   apartments are available for sale. Give a recursive denition of P(b;
>   a).

Does anyone of you have an idea how to solve this recursively?

Thanks

Comment: I have solved other dynamic programming and recursion problems in the past (fibonacci, selling different wines in different years etc.) but here I can't seem to find a final condition that makes sense to me...I have tried to abort when there are no more apartments left, no more buyers left, but then the recursive calls are not possible to code...

Answer (score 0):

1.) Form an array containing the values of (p/s) like [2,2,2,2,1,5,5,3,3,3]. I'm assuming here that no value of (p/s) will result in a decimal number.

2.)Now, you can reduce this problem to a K-combination problem where k=8 (number of apartments to be sold).

3.) Print out all the combinations with k=8 and n being the values in the array, and you will see that the maximum value you get with this approach is 20.

Answer (score 0):

Think this might work.

```
class ApartmentBuyer{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int noOfApartments=10;
        System.out.println("Program to find maximum profit from given set of buyers and apartments. \n total number of apartments="+noOfApartments);
        int [] buyersNeed= {4, 1, 2, 3};
        int [] price={8, 1, 10, 9};
        print(buyersNeed);
        print(price);
        System.out.println("Maximum Profit="+findMaxProfit(noOfApartments,buyersNeed,price,price.length-1,0));

    }

    /**
    *b={4} and p={1} and noOfApratment=4 , max profit=4
    *b={4,1} and price{1,5} noOfApartment= 1, max profit=4
    *Start from right most and go forward for recurence
    **/
    public static int findMaxProfit(int noOfApartments, int need[], int[] price, int pos, int profit){

        if(need==null || price==null || need.length<1 || price.length<1 || price.length!=need.length|| pos<0 || pos>need.length) return profit;
        if(noOfApartments<=0) return profit;
        int currentProfit=0;
        if(need[pos]<=noOfApartments) currentProfit= profit+need[pos]*price[pos];
        System.out.println("No Of Apartments:"+noOfApartments+ "\t pos:"+pos+"\t profit:"+profit+ "\tneed[pos]"+need[pos]);noOfApartments
        System.out.println("No Of Apartments:"+noOfApartments+ "\t pos:"+pos+"\t profit:"+profit+ "\tneed[pos]"+need[pos]);noOfApartments
        return Math.max(findMaxProfit(noOfApartments-need[pos],need,price, pos-1,currentProfit), findMaxProfit(noOfApartments,need,price,pos-1,profit));

    }


    static void print(int... arr){
        if(arr==null || arr.length<1) return;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i:arr)System.out.print(i+" ");
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Printing Matrix
void printdpmatrix(int l1, int l2, int dp[l1+1][l2+1]){
    for (int i= 0; i < l1+1; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0 ; j < l2+1; j++){
            printf("|%d|",dp[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
// Simple Max Function.
int max(int a, int b){return a > b ? a : b;}

// Returns maximum profit.
int maxprofit(int forsale, int* demand, int* price, int length){
    int ans;
    int sell;
    int notsell;
    //Declare Dp Matrix, +1 to accomodate the 0/0 basecase.  
    int dp[length+1][forsale+1];
    //Initialise matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < forsale+1; i++){dp[0][i] = 0;}
    for (int j = 0; j < length+1; j++){dp[j][0] = 0;}

    // Main logic loop 
    // i is the buyers 
    // j is the apartments
    for (int i = 1; i < length +  1; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < forsale + 1; j++){
            //If we don't consider the current buyer we look at one buyer less. 
            notsell = dp[i-1][j];
            sell = 0; 
            //If the demand exceeds the supply, we can't sell anything. 
            if (demand[i-1] > j){ sell = 0;}
            //If we have the supply to cope with the demaind then we take
            //the profit of the current item and add the profit of this item 
            //disconsidered and with the supply reduced by the demand of this item. 
            else{ sell = price[i-1] + dp[i-1][j - (demand[i-1])];}
            //Update the DP matrix.
            dp[i][j] = max(sell,notsell);
            }
    }
    // Print matrix for fun. 
    printdpmatrix(length, forsale, dp);
    // Answer = last position in matrix. 
    ans = dp[length][forsale];
    // Print the answer for fun. 
    printf(" \n %d <-ANS\n",ans);
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    int houses = 8;
    int demand[4] = {4,1,2,3};
    int price[4] = {8,1,10,9};
    int length = 4; 
    maxprofit(houses, demand, price, length);

    return 0;
}
```

Better late than never ;) Greetings from Info 2.